# How to read off a scatter with smooth lines graph on excel?

Tags: excel

Hi I have attached my graph and my data below: 
[image]

[image]

My experiment is on Simple Harmonic Oscillators in an RLC circuit. I need to work out the quality factor. Where I need delta w which is the width of the resonance curve at imax/sqrt(2). With the Y axis being my current and Imax being 0.4229 so 0.4229/sqrt(2) = 0.299. So I need to read the frequencies (x values) at the points 0.299 on the y axis in order to work out the width. I was wondering how I can do this on excel. Obviously if this was on paper I could just draw straight lines but I'm on excel and unsure and hoping someone could help. Thanks

Comment: This looks more like a math question than an Excel question.

Comment: No it isn't really isn't I just need to know how to find x values using my graph. It's just I can't use regression obviously as it's a smooth line graph.

Comment: Design > Add chart element > Display all grid lines.. Format > Series1 > marker size = smaller.  It'll help to pin point the value better. I get 2310 for y.